# Swift Stack Proxy Server Reboot

Tags: linux, s3cmd, swift

I'm fairly new to Object Storage and have been thrown into support for an old product we no longer have a support contract for and therefore can't seek help from the vendor.

I have a 13-node cluster, 10 object nodes, and 3 proxy nodes. I'm wondering if it's ok to sequentially reboot all 3 proxy nodes without causing any concern for the actual object nodes.

I have seen this done before and it didn't seem to cause any problems but I want to make sure before I reboot each node individually.

Also, I assume since these nodes are running Linux there is no trick I can just issue a reboot like any other Linux OS? I can't seem to find any information about rebooting the proxies and any gotchas I need to be aware of ahead of time.

Thanks in advance!